# Copy one recursive list to another

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am using EF core to fetch `CategoryMaster` table from the database using the following model:

```
public class DtoCategoryMaster 
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int parent_category_id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string category_type { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string category_name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int display_order { get; set; }
    
    public DateTime date_created {get; set;}
    
    public DateTime date_modified {get; set;}
    
    [ForeignKey("parent_category_id")]
    public virtual DtoCategoryMaster Parent { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<DtoCategoryMaster> Children { get; set; }
}
```

I want to copy the above DataTrasfer object (Dto) to the `CategoryMasterViewModel` Class's object. Definition of the same class is as below:

```
public class GetCategoryMasterViewModel 
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string category_name { get; set; }
    
    public int display_order {get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<GetCategoryMasterViewModel> Children { get; set; }
}
```

I tried many ways (like tried to use automapper, tried to use mapping mechanism of linq, etc) to do the same but facing issues while mapping Children object of `CategoryMasterViewModel` to the object of `DtoCategoryMaster`

Here my primary aim is, I want to return only required properties from the API, here `date_created` and `date_modified` is not required. That's why created new ViewModel which does not contains such properties.

Basically, I need proper mapping logic between `DtoCategoryMaster` and `CategoryMasterViewModel`.

Please do not suggest alternate ways like putting [JsonIgore] or [XmlIgore].

Comment: Thanks, @Vimal for formatting my question

Comment: Can you post your mapping logic code

Comment: I exactly need that. That is the thing which I don't know :(

Comment: Where are `id` and `category_name` mapped from? They aren't declared in `DtoCategoryMaster`.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay, I added it :)

Comment: you said you want to copy your dto to your view model, but then indicate attempts and issues mapping property of view model to the dto.  First, please provide your linq attempt showing your work and clarify what issue you're having with that attempt.  Also, update your question to better clarify whether you're having issues mapping view model to dto, dto to view model, or both.

Comment: The way classes are presented I see no real issue for Automapper to the job without any specific settings. A profile of the type: `CreateMap<DtoCategoryMaster, CategoryMasterViewModel>();` seems enough. Could you share what are the errors you are facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding a factory method to your `GetCategoryMasterViewModel`:

```
public class GetCategoryMasterViewModel 
{
    //...

    public static GetCategoryMasterViewModel From(DtoCategoryMaster dto)
    {
        return new GetCategoryMasterViewModel
        {
            id = dto.id,
            category_name = dto.category_name,
            display_order = dto.display_order,
            Children = dto.Children?.Select(From).ToList()
        };
    }
}
```

Then you can use like this:

```
var model = GetCategoryMasterViewModel.From(dto);
```

You could even define an implicit conversion:

```
public class GetCategoryMasterViewModel 
{
    //...

   public static implicit operator GetCategoryMasterViewModel(DtoCategoryMaster dto)
       => From(dto);
}
```

Then you could do this:

```
GetCategoryMasterViewModel model = dto;
```

Comment: Thank you @Jonathan, This is perfect solution

Answer (score 0):

Multiple approaches are there to solve your issue. You can write your own method to map two objects or use an `AutoMapper` nuget library. I would prefer `AutoMapper`

You can use below code to Map the objects with inner collection

```
public void MapTheCollection()
{
     var lst = new List<DtoCategoryMaster>();
     for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
     {
         lst.Add(new DtoCategoryMaster() { id = i, category_name = $"{i} Name", display_order = i, Children =  new List<DtoCategoryMaster>()
                {
                     new DtoCategoryMaster(){ id = i},
                     new DtoCategoryMaster() {id = i + 1}
         }});
     }



     var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cf =>
     {
          cf.CreateMap<DtoCategoryMaster, GetCategoryMasterViewModel>()
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.id))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.category_name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.category_name))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.display_order, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.display_order));
    });

    var mapper = new Mapper(configuration);
    var output = mapper.Map<List<DtoCategoryMaster>, List<GetCategoryMasterViewModel>>(lst);
}
```

You do not need to map both source and destination field using `ForMember` as both field names in your case is same. I have included that in case you need to map different properties in the future.